# compilers implemented / written in PHP? [or javascript : see edit]

Tags: compiler-construction

I have a server that generates numerical data 6 to 11 dimensional. So far, I had a text box where the user could give in a command, such as OVERLAYDATA SRC="some/source/uri" COLS=columen,name,and,such COLOR=(color_min_red ...)(...color_max_blue) and this will display the data points with color encoding on an openlayer map. So far so good, all fine. In the backend, of course the color codings are generated via php, which echoes a line in the web page source, which is a call to openlayer, and when the browser sees the line, the openlayer point objects are shown all right.

Now I want to add some further interactivity. I want to support user defined transformations to the data. For that, I imagine, if there is a language, which has a compiler written in (that is, NOT compiles to, but has a compiler written in) PHP. The user could use this (hopefully simple) language to define his wished transformation like

```
function res = some_transformation(data)
{ //do some voodoo here
}
some_transformation(__datasource);
```

Obviously there will be some further keywords, such as __datasource, which will point to a speciific source which the compiler itself does not need to know of.

SO i was looking for the said compilers and found only this so far :

https://github.com/alxlit/coffeescript-php

As I understand, if you program a script in coffeescript, and feed the correct data, the php at the background will accept the data, and do what you programmed in coffeescript, and send you the result back.

I hope I managed to clarify what I am looking for.

Now the question : are any other such nice softwares available?

## edit 1 :

as it has been pointed out that this could lead to security vulnerability, I am wondering if first accessing only allowed data, and then doing the compilation in client side (i.e. javascript?)  would change the scenario and make things less vulnerable ?

if so, then which ones? I find a C complier written in Javascript, but that is a bit overkill.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with that approach of using an existing language is that you have to control on the backend which features you grant and which not. Otherwise you have a huge security problem since you might unvoluntary offer access to things you do not wish to be accessed.

You can prevent this if you define an own language for the purpose at hand. In case of a limited set of required features this is not too much work. To process (here: compile) such self defined language the selection of "compiler compilers" come in handy. We once implemented a complex search language based on that approach once. Take a look at [yacc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc) or its GNU counterpart [bison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_bison) for this!

Comment: i am not aware of bison / yacc to work with php - but this : http://sourceforge.net/projects/lime-php/ - with that in mind, yes i considered my own language, but somehow - forgive this please - i felt too it would be too cheesy. Having said that, a goto and a if statement would suffice, along with an extensive math support, which i probably can take care off using either http://www.phpmath.com/home or math.js, before commiting the send action, but I would still like to see what other options are available.

Comment: You can use bison or yacc within php like any other command: you simply call it as a cli command and return the result. That works fine.